# Group By Top N DAX Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery

Say I have 4 regions: A, B, C, D, key, and values.
How can I structure a DAX query to get

1. The top N keys
2. by value (descending)
3. for ***each*** of the regions?
   So basically, top 100 keys for A by value, top 100 keys for B by value, etc.

Something like

```
EVALUATE
TOPN (
    100,
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS( 
                key, 
                region), 
        value, 
        [DESC]
    )
```

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for the results from the first part of this article- topN by group: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/filtering-the-top-products-alongside-the-other-products-in-power-bi/  This is before they get into the "All Others" category.  If you provide some example data with your table structure, we can get at a query that you could actually use

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Calculated table and use this code:

```
CalcTable =
VAR RegionSelected = "A"
RETURN
    TOPN (
        100,
        FILTER ( YourTable, YourTable[region] = RegionSelected ),
        value, DESC
    )
```

Just change the variable to B, C, D ... etc to see whatever region table you want!.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GENERATE to attach top 100 rows for the same region.

```
EVALUATE 
    GENERATE ( 
        VALUES ( Region[Region] ),
        CALCULATETABLE ( 
            TOPN ( 
                100,
                VALUES ( Region[Keys] ),
                [Measure]
            )
        )
    )
```